# Adding Array to Hash of Arrays without Reference

Tags: perl

I'm working with an API to get Information and save it into a file

```
#!/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my %Hash;
my @Array;
my $url = "https://foo/bar"
my $apidata = `/usr/bin/curl -k -u $url`
my $apidatajson = decode_json $apidata;
my $i=0;

foreach(@{ $apidatajson->{category} }){
   @Array=();
   my $Name=$apidatajson->{category}[$i]{Name};
   my $value=$apidatajson->{category}[$i]{Value};
   
   push(@Array,($Name,$value));
   $Hash{$Name}=@Array; # Output 1
   $Hash{$Name}=\@Array; # Output 2

   $i++;

}
print Dumper \%Hash;
```

Output 1 looks something like this:

```
$VAR1{
  "FooName2" => 2;
  "FooName" => 2;
};
```

Output 2 looks something like this:

```
$VAR1{
  "FooName2" => [
               "FooName2"
               "FooValue2"
              ]
   "FooName" => $VAR1 -> {'FooName2'}
};
```

Id need it to look like this:

```
$VAR1 {
   "FooName2" => [
               "FooName2"
               "FooValue2"
                ]   
   "FooName" => [
               "FooName"
               "FooValue"
                ]
}
```

So essentially what I'm asking is, how can I save the content of the Array in the Hash, without using a Reference, so it doesn't mess up every entry but the last one?

Comment: You are missing a `}` on the line of the `foreach`. Futhermore, your code does not reproduce the issue you are talking about (probably because you added a `my` before `@Array=()` within the loop). Finally, you are using double quotes instead of backticks around `curl https:/foo/bar`. Next time, please test your code before posting a question.

Comment: (just realized my previous comment sounds a bit harsher that I would have liked): you were right to simplify your code before posting, and we appreciate. Next time, just run it locally after the simplification and before posting ;) Anyway, welcome on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your question is not the code you are running. In particular, I suspect that you do not have the line `my @Array = ()` but rather `@Array = ()` (without `my`).

Thus, `$Hash{$Name} = \@Array;` takes the reference of the array declared outside of the `foreach` loop (since there is actually none declared within the loop), which is why both values of your hashtable are the same.

If you declare `@Array` within your loop, the your code works properly.

Additional notes:

- Your seem confused between the "foreach" loop and the C-style for loop. Your loop should be:

  ```
   for (@{ $apidatajson->{category}}){
       my @Array;
       my $Name  = $_->{Name};
       my $value = $_->{Value};

       push(@Array,($Name,$value));
       $Hash{$Name} = \@Array;
   }
  ```

  Or, since you don't really need `@Array`, simply:

  ```
   for (@{ $apidatajson->{category}}){
       my $Name  = $_->{Name};
       my $value = $_->{Value};

       $Hash{$Name} = [$Name, $value];
   }
  ```

  Or, if you need to keep your `$i`:

  ```
   for my $i (0 .. $#{$apidatajson->{category}}) {
        my $Name  = $apidatajson->{category}[$i]{Name};
        my $value = $apidatajson->{category}[$i]{Value};

        $Hash{$Name} = [$Name, $value];
   }
  ```
- You don't need to call `curl` to do an http request. Instead, you can use a Perl module like [`LWP::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Simple):

  ```
   use LWP::Simple;
   my $apidata = get("https://foo/bar") or die "Failed to get data from API!";
  ```

Comment: I think you may also be confused with the distinction between `for` and `foreach`. Perl doesn't care which name you use for the loop - just what's inside the parens. The names `for` and `foreach` are interchangeable either way. Something looking like `for (@list)` results in a foreach loop and something like `foreach (my $i = 0; $i < $n; ++$i)` will result in a for loop. The difference is that foreach will implicitly localize a previously declared iteration variable, so it will revert to the value it had outside the loop, once the loop exits.

Comment: @Silvar I am well away that `for` and `foreach` are interchangeable. However, saying "you seem confused between for and for" seems less clear than "you seem confused between foreach and c-style for". Furthermore, if you look at the [documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#For-Loops), you'll notice that the terms "foreach" and "C-style for" are used in the same way as they are in my answer.

Comment: @Silvar Furthermore, the remark in my answer about for loops is not about "for vs foreach" but rather about the usefulness of doing `my $i = 0; for (@array) { f($array[$i]); $i++ }` rather than `for (@array) { f($_) }`. I'd say that anyone doing the former missed the point of foreach loops.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$Hash{$Name}=[$Name, $value];
```

Square brackets are array references in Perl.

You can not avoid an array reference, if you need it. Your requirements are contradictory.

BTW: what you have created in the second version is a cyclic reference. Probably because of the same variable name in the global and local scope. But I think the output does not belong to your code.

Comment: yes, its the other way round so "FooName" => $VAR1 -> {'FooName2'}, if you dont mean that then maybe I missed something when simplifying my code, sorry if that is the case.